# Nullpointer in Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i´m getting a NullPointerException when i do the connection to my API using Volley, this is the method i'm using:

```
 List<Empresas> empresas = rellenar();




 private List<Empresas> rellenar() {
    final List<Empresas> empresas2 = null;

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "APIurl",(JSONObject)null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                        int id;
                        String nombre_franquicia;
                        String nombre_categoria;
                        String nombre;
                        String descripcion;
                        String contenido;
                        String direccion;
                        String foto_negocio;
                        String foto_principal;
                        String horario;
                        String telefono;
                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject objeto = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            if (objeto.getString("id") != null && objeto.getString("id")!="null") {
                                id = Integer.parseInt(objeto.getString("id"));
                            } else {
                                id = 0;
                            }
                            if (objeto.getString("nombre_franquicia")!=null && objeto.getString("nombre_franquicia")!="null"){
                                nombre_franquicia = objeto.getString("nombre_franquicia");
                            }else{
                                nombre_franquicia = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("nombre_categoria")!=null && objeto.getString("nombre_categoria")!="null") {
                                nombre_categoria = objeto.getString("nombre_categoria");
                            }else{
                                nombre_categoria = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("nombre")!=null && objeto.getString("nombre")!="null") {
                                nombre = objeto.getString("nombre");
                            }else{
                                nombre = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("descripcion")!=null  && objeto.getString("descripcion")!="null") {
                                descripcion = objeto.getString("descripcion");
                            }else{
                                descripcion = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.get("contenido")!=null  && objeto.getString("contenido")!="null") {
                                contenido = objeto.getString("contenido");
                            }else{
                                contenido = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("direccion")!=null && objeto.getString("direccion")!="null") {
                                direccion = objeto.getString("direccion");
                            }else{
                                direccion = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("foto_negocio")!=null && objeto.getString("foto_negocio")!="null") {
                                foto_negocio = objeto.getString("foto_negocio");
                            }else{
                                foto_negocio = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("foto_principal")!=null && objeto.getString("foto_principal")!="null") {
                                foto_principal = objeto.getString("foto_principal");
                            }
                            else{
                                foto_principal = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("horario")!=null && objeto.getString("horario")!="null") {
                                horario = objeto.getString("horario");
                            }else{
                                horario = "No disponible";
                            }
                            if(objeto.getString("telefono")!=null && objeto.getString("telefono")!="null") {
                                telefono = objeto.getString("telefono");
                            }
                            else{
                                telefono = "No disponible";
                            }



                            Empresas negocio = new Empresas( id,nombre_franquicia, nombre_categoria, nombre, descripcion,
                                    contenido, direccion, foto_negocio,foto_principal, horario,telefono);

                            empresas2.add(negocio);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
      new Response.ErrorListener(){
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Log.e("VOLLEY","ERROR");
          }
      }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    return empresas2;
}
```

When the activity starts the `List<Empresas> empresas` calls the method in the onCreateView of the fragment and after a few seconds i get a NullPointerException in `empresas2.add(negocio)` it's the first time i'm working with Volley and i dont understand it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`final List<Empresas> empresas2 = null;` is NULL assign in your code.

Replace with:

```
List<Empresas> empresas2 = new ArrayList<Empresas>();
```

Comment: my god, i can't belive i didn't notice it, i feel so dumb right now